# Misconduct from my head and how to reply to disrespectful emails

Tags: personal-misconduct

I am a dr. in statistics. I got a job in one university and found that it is extremely bad. After only one semester I resigned. Then, for the second semester I got a job at another university.  My head come to evaluate me at one of my classes. She and another doctor were laughing and discussing personal issues while I was giving my class. Even my students told me that the noise was coming from the evaluation panel! Then, I was surprised that my evaluation was very very low. I told them that they were laughing and busy while I was teaching and that they did not listen to me and hence missed many parts (they evaluated me on the missing parts)! They told me that they would not change their opinion.

I sent an email to my manager about that, she sent my email back to them. They become so angry with me. Then they met me and started shouting at me on why I sent the email to the dean about them. One of them, my head, shouted at me, putting her finger in my face telling me “you did not raising well” that means you are a very bad person. And then she said to me that you are zero very loudly. Then she said to me, your last employer accepted you to leave during the year (after the first semester) because you are under expectations!

I am really sad and feel bad. How can I respond to her especially for saying that I am bad and that why my old employer did not mind to let me leave. I swear I left them as they were very bad.

Comment: It appears relevant to know your country of employment. Is this a private or a public institution? It is not clear to me exactly what you wish to achieve. Clearly, their behavior is unacceptable.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are going through this. The behavior of the evaluating (head and doctor) seems very inappropriate. Your best bet is if you can get someone on your side. Is the dean supportive? That could be a very useful way to get this behavior to stop.

Comment: @Carl Christian it is a private school. I just would like to know  how can I respond to her in written email. How can I explain that she has no write to assume I leave the uni because I am bad.

Comment: @6005 the dean seems to be with them.

Comment: This seems a ridiculous scenario. Leave it again when possible. Also it does not seem an academia scenario. Bad things happen in academia, of course. But at different levels or at least, with rather good acting skills....